# How to create an array of RichTextBox's in c#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, winforms, richtextbox

I am working on a desktop app and i am struck on this code, i want to create 15 richtextboxes directly below one another. but its been giving me an error of "Object reference not set to ..." something like that.

```
        RichTextBox[] richboxes = new RichTextBox[14];
        Array rboxarray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(RichTextBox),14);
        int y = 128;
        int j = 0;
        foreach(RichTextBox rbox in rboxarray)
        {
            Controls.Add(rbox);
            rbox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, y);
            rbox.Name = "richTextBox"+ (12+j);
            rbox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(671, 68);
            rbox.TabIndex = 41 + j;
            rbox.Text = "";
            y += 70;
            j++;
        }
```

But error on the line `rbox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, y);`.
please provide me the right code.

Comment: Can you provide the whole error?

Comment: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ProjectYello.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Check before rbox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, y); if the rbox != null while debugging.

Comment: Error comes on first iteration of foreach loop ?

Comment: You create an array of references, but you did not instantiate any objects.

Comment: but it is showing rbox = null for while debugging, thats why its giving error i think.

Comment: Yes, so as i said before, use @Smartis post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With For-Loop at the RichTextBoy-Array-Instance it will work:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < richboxes.Length; i++)
        {
            richboxes[i] = new RichTextBox(); // Instance the TextBox

            Controls.Add(richboxes[i]);
            richboxes[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, y);
            richboxes[i].Name = "richTextBox" + (12 + j);
            richboxes[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(671, 68);
            richboxes[i].TabIndex = 41 + j;
            richboxes[i].Text = "";
            y += 70;
            j++;
        }
```

Comment: Error: "Cannot assign to 'rbox' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'" on line "rbox = new RichTextBox();".

Comment: @HTD look at the up-vote number, you should replace the `foreach` with a normal `for-loop`

Comment: yup, that did it. Thanks. But any way to add these generated richtextboxes in a tabpage not in the Form?

Answer (score 0):

```
      RichTextBox[] txt = new RichTextBox[15];

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            txt[i] = new RichTextBox();
            txt[i].Text = "";
            if (i > 0)
            {
                txt[i].Left = txt[i - 1].Right;
            }

            this.Controls.Add(txt[i]);
        }
```